# testNG: How to capture return value of test case either in @AfterMethod or listener?

Tags: testng

just to set the context, my test case creates some data and i want to delete that data in teardown. i would like to implement generic teardown process (through AfterMethod/AfterClass/Listener) in such a way that it will inspect the return value (and its type, mostly domain objects) and cleans up the data(some thing like below).

```
public class SampleTest {

@AfterMethod
public void teardown(Object returnValueFromTest){
    //inspect returnValueFromTest and perform necessary clean up.
}

@Test
public String testEventGeneration(){
    //generate event

    //returning generated event id.
    return "E1234";
}

@Test
public Market testMarketGeneration(){
    //generate market

    //returning generated market.
    return someMarket;
}}
```

any ideas/thoughts on how to achieve this in testNG? I considered implementing a listener like IHookable as well but could not find the listener that can help me get hold of return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply handle this ,If you want to wind out everything after all tests are executed you have to use @AfterClass annotation instead of @AfterMethod annotation. @AfterMethod annotation triggers after every test method in the test class.

And flowing code will simply do your task . If you want to implement this in listner level you can implement **ITestListener** and on onFinish method you can implement your logic.

public class SampleTest {
private String event_id = null;

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void teardown(){
    //delete event from the db(event_id) 

}

@Test
public void testEventGeneration(){
    //generate event

    //returning generated event id.
    event_Id= "E1234";
}}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but that is not what i am looking for. i want to implement teardown process (through AfterMethod/AfterClass/Listener) in such a way that it will inspect the return value (and its type, mostly domain objects) and cleans up the data. in other words, depending on the domain object that will be returned from the test case, teardown method/listener will know what to delete and perform the cleanup. the key here is to automate the teardown process, i do not want to maintain local instances in every single test just for tearing down unless there is no other better way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Testng wouldn't even execute methods annotated as Test if there is a return value associated with them.

So, if you want to teardown based on values set, then you would need to set those values in a global context or externally and not as return values.  You can write your teardown logic either as a listener or in any of the After methods, based on when you want to teardown.

Comment: actually you can enable testcases to return values in testNG. <suite allow-return-values="true"> or <test allow-return-values="true">

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using InvokedMethodListener2?

```
public Class BaseTestNg {

    ITestContext ctx;

    public ITestContext getContext(){
        return this.ctx;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setContext( final ITestContext ctx ) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}

public Class SampleTest extends BaseTestNg {

    @Test
    public Market testMarketGeneration(){
        //generate market
        this.getContext().setAttribute("market", someMarket);
        //returning generated market.
        return someMarket;
    }
}


import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener2;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class InvokedMethodListener2Impl implements IInvokedMethodListener2 {

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation( final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation( final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult, final ITestContext context ) {

        //read object from context
        //Market = (Market) context.getAttribute("market");

        // testResult.setStatus( ITestResult.FAILURE );

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation( final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation( final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult, final ITestContext context ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```